# Factory Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => DataAd' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have trying to figure out in some question but there is no case like me. I am getting the code from tutorial and I have understand it. However, the problem is in the tutorial. It uses static JSON (list) where mine using dynamic which contain keys.

Here is my code

```
class CompileAd {
  String status;
  String notification;
  Map<int,DataAd> adData;

  CompileAd({
    required this.status,
    required this.notification,
    required this.adData,
  });

  factory CompileAd.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CompileAd(
        status: json["status"],
        notification: json["notification"],
        adData: Map<int,DataAd>.from(
            json["adData"].map((x) => DataAd.fromJson(x))), => ERROR HERE
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "notification": notification,
        "adData": Map<dynamic,dynamic>.from(adData.map((key,x) => x.toJson())), => HERE ALSO (Actually, I wish to use "jsonEncode(adData)" since its working but no idea which one better)
      };
}
```

Error Log

> lib/class/adClass.dart:27:69: Error: A value of type 'Map<String,
> dynamic>' can't be returned from a function with return type
> 'MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>'.
>
> - 'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
> - 'MapEntry' is from 'dart:core'.
>   "adData": Map<dynamic,dynamic>.from(adData.map((key,x) => x.toJson())),
>   ^

Here is the json object

adData => (keyID,adObject)

```
{
    "adData": {
        "77289": {
            "id": 77289,
            "username": "magdatjahja@gmail.com",
            "category": "rumah",
            "subCategory": "rumah",
            "type": "dijual",
            "uniqueId": "6436",
            "title": "Jual Rumah di Mazenta Bintaro Tangerang Selatan",
            "slug": "jual-rumah-di-mazenta-bintaro-tangerang-selatan",
            "content": "Jual rumah di mazento bintaro tangerang selatan\r\n\r\nSatu-satunya hunian premium di kawasan Bintaro bernuansa Japan Ambiance Living :\r\n\r\nType unit :\r\n\ud83d\udc49 Type 6 \r\nLuas Tanah: 72m2 \r\nLuas Bangunan: 83m2 \r\nKamar Tidur: 3 \r\nKamar Mandi: 2 \r\n\r\n\ud83c\udf81Dapatkan Promo Early Bird Price !!!\ud83c\udf81\r\n\u2705HARGA MULAI RP.1,8 M\r\n\u27053 unit AC 1 Pk\r\n\u2705Free Mini Canopy\r\n\u2705 Lucky Bowl up to Iphone13\r\n\u2705 SmartDoorlock\r\n\r\nLokasi\r\n\ud83d\ude97 Hanya 3 menit ke BXchange Mall Bintaro!\r\n\ud83d\ude97 Hanya 2-3 menit ke pintu tol! dan jumlah unit SANGAT terbatas!\r\n\ud83d\ude97Hanya 3 Menit Statiun Jurang Mangu\r\n\ud83d\ude97Hanya 3 menit UPJ University\r\n\r\n\r\nHubungi AGENT MERKETING\r\nMagda 08118897878",
            "bid": 2000,
            "balance": 1,
            "price": "1800000000",
            "province": "banten",
            "regency": "tangerang selatan",
            "district": "",
            "village": "",
            "complex": "",
            "rd": 1,
            "premier": "2022-03-22 11:33:13",
            "partner": 1,
            "privateSync": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "penaltyTime": null,
            "data": {
                "price": {
                    "price": "1800000000"
                },
                "priceUnit": "",
                "province": "banten",
                "regency": "tangerang selatan",
                "district": "",
                "village": "",
                "additional": {
                    "address": "Bintaro, Tangerang Selatan",
                    "complex": "",
                    "lt": "72",
                    "lb": "83",
                    "bedroom": "3",
                    "bathroom": "2",
                    "maidbedroom": "",
                    "maidbathroom": "",
                    "floor": "",
                    "garage": "",
                    "carports": "",
                    "electricity": "",
                    "orientation": "",
                    "interior": ""
                },
                "facebook": "2022-03-22 14:54:05",
                "twitter": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                "pinterest": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                "tumblr": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
                "premier": "2022-03-22 11:33:13",
                "partner": true,
                "penaltyTime": "2022-03-22 11:32:01",
                "instagram": "2022-03-22 14:47:14"
            },
            "images": {
                "images": ["jual-rumah-di-mazenta-bintaro-tangerang-selatan-0XOV3B.jpg", "jual-rumah-di-mazenta-bintaro-tangerang-selatan-VS38QN.jpg", "jual-rumah-di-mazenta-bintaro-tangerang-selatan-14RHI3.jpg"],
                "imagesAdditional": [],
                "images360": []
            },
            "video": {
                "1": "https:\/\/youtu.be\/CA6iNWEDa1E"
            },
            "sosmed": 0,
            "view": 28,
            "contact": 0,
            "status": "active",
            "checked": 1,
            "sold": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "modify": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
            "waktu": "2022-03-21 17:40:03",
            "dir": "\/uploads\/images\/2022\/03\/77289\/",
            "url": "\/properti\/tangerang-selatan\/6436-jual-rumah-di-mazenta-bintaro-tangerang-selatan\/"
        }
    },
    "status": "success",
    "notification": "Berhasil memproses permintaan"
}
```

I really appreciate any answers. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `Map<int,DataAd>.from` try `Map<int,DataAd>.fromIterable`

Comment: I have tried to use it, but it shown "Error: A value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be returned from a function with return type 'MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>".

Comment: You can define your `key` and `value` types inside of `fromIterable` method. Documentation: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/Map/Map.fromIterable.html

Comment: Its working, thank you. However, I am using the basic code from the documentation. Why the tutorial code does not work? since its quite simple tho. Is it only work for List type?

Comment: It should be doable, I don't know what did you mess up. Maybe you can update your question with the new error (problem).